# Spectral density of sampled process

Tags: sampling, stationarity

A real valued time-continuous process $X(t)$ is described by the spectral density according to the top of the image below. The process is sampled with the sampling distance $d=1/40$. The question is to determine the spectral density for the sampled process.

The bottom three graphs are supposed to be the solution and answer. But how should it be interpreted? Is the solution the bottom graph? That would make sense since high (and low?) frequencies are lost in the sampling. What does the third one say then? And what do the different colours in the second one represent?

[image: Spectrum]

The question and image is from an exam in Stationary stochastic processes at Bachelor level.